# App implementing Parse Unity Plugin crashes on android device but works fine in editor

Tags: c#, android, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use Parse in my Unity game in order to implement high scores. My problem is that when I try to put the game on my android device to test it, the name of the app comes up different. It comes up as "ParseUnityPushSample" even though I have not changed anything besides adding the files that Parse gives me to use it. The build settings have not changed and it even shows that my package name is the same, yet testing it on a device has this result.

Testing it in Unity 5 works fine. The game loads as it should. This only happens when I try to put it on a device for testing.

Along with it changing the app name, it also crashes when opening. I get a prompt that says "ParseUnityPushSample" has failed anytime I try to open it on an android device.

EDIT:

Okay so I figured out a way to view some errors that occur when testing on a device. I get this error: "Unable to find unity activity in manifest. You need to make sure orientation attribute is set to sensorLandscape manually.
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun()" I have no idea what the issue is though since I have manually set the orientation for the activity to sensorLandscape in the Android Manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.laserdeflector.sab" android:versionName="1.0.1" android:versionCode="1" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="com.laserdeflector.sab.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.laserdeflector.sab.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<application android:label="Laser Deflector" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape" android:name="com.soomla.SoomlaApp" android:debuggable="false" android:isGame="true">
<activity android:name=".UnityPlayerActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name="com.laserdeflector.sab" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.parse.ParsePushService" />
<activity android:name="com.soomla.store.billing.google.GooglePlayIabService$IabActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
<meta-data android:name="billing.service" android:value="google.GooglePlayIabService" />
</application>
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

**8/10/15**

I have come to learn that this may be an issue with Parse v1.5.2 although changing to v1.3.2 did not help with the issue I am facing either. I will update as soon as I learn anything more.

**8/11/15**

Updating to v1.5.4 did not fix the issue either. Still having problems with the android manifest with the same error message. If anyone has any idea please let me know!

Comment: Without any logs, it would be hard for anyone to help you, especially with the crash issue.

Comment: @Stralo I understand this...but with unity it doesn't exactly give me a logcat or anything like I would have with Android studio when I am trying to run this on a device.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that Parse is modifying the manifest with the app name you're seeing. Something that won't show up in Unity. So I'd have a look at that.

Comment: yes you can generate logcat file through terminal. https://unitycodes.wordpress.com/2015/02/07/how-to-set-up-adb-in-terminal-on-mac/

Comment: @NeerajKumar I need to do that even though I added the edit with an error above?

Comment: Seems like you have many manifest file in your project, and some of them are clashing or not properly configured.

Comment: @NeerajKumar I do have an android manifest that comes with Parse in a plugins folder. I have added it above. I don't know what could be wrong with it. It seems okay to me.

Comment: yes, indeed there is a problem in your manifest file. please check my answer.

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the correct parse app key ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, just taking the Unity sdk was not the answer. In order to make it work I had to use what was in the Unity blank project and then I also deleted the android manifest that v1.5.2 included in the sdk. Doing both of these things allowed the app to work correctly on my android device.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is in your manifest file, you have changed the following lines

```
<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

<service android:name="com.parse.ParsePushService" />
```

to this

```
<receiver android:name="com.laserdeflector.PushBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">

<service android:name="com.laserdeflector.ParsePushService" />
```

Here is the correct manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.laserdeflector.sab"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="com.laserdeflector.sab.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.laserdeflector.sab.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

  <application android:label="LaserDeflector" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon">
    <activity android:name=".UnityPlayerActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="com.laserdeflector.sab" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.parse.ParsePushService" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: After trying out what you said, the app still crashes with the same error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Manifest was an obvious issue but still it is not working, then it could be the parse sdk bug. You can revert to Parse Unity SDK v1.3.2. looks like other people also having this problem with latest sdk. Go to the following link - http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/986245/parse-and-unity5-for-android-broke.html?sort=oldest

Comment: I am just not having any luck. I took what was in the v1.3.2 download had in that post and I have no changes. It still crashes with the same error.

Comment: I don't know if it has anything to do with it, but the download for v1.3.2 didn't have theh link.xml or the plugins folder so I don't know how that affects things with the different version

Comment: Also if it had to do with the Parse api, wouldn't I have issues writing to Parse in the editor? Because it writes out to Parse just fine.

Comment: I added what is in Parse v1.5.4 and still no luck. I still get the same errors. Do you think it could be something in the manifest if this many different versions is still breaking in my game?